# VB SQL DELETE Statement Not Working - No Error At All

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-delete

This is my Code and it just doesn't work, I'm trying to make it Delete a record where the column staffID is equal to the variable currentStaffID although it doesn't delete the record or give an error, it just carries on and displays the MsgBox after the DELETE Statement.

```
Dim AreYouSureEdit = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

    If DbConnect() And AreYouSureEdit = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        SQLCmd.Connection = cn
        currentStaffID = editStaffIDTxtBox.Text()

        SQLCmd.CommandText = "DELETE * STAFF WHERE staffID = @currentStaffID"
        cn.Close()

        MsgBox("Record Deleted.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up your command and everything - but you're never **executing** it! Of course nothing happens.....

You need to add one line of code:

```
Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
SQLCmd.Connection = cn
currentStaffID = editStaffIDTxtBox.Text()

SQLCmd.CommandText = "DELETE * STAFF WHERE staffID = ?"

'' You need to define the parameter and set its value here!
SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.Int).Value = currentStaffID;

'' you need to actually **EXECUTE** your DELETE query!
SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

cn.Close()
```

Also, while you're setting up a parameter in your SQL query text just fine, I don't see where you're actually defining such a parameter on your `SQLCmd` object - and also be aware: OleDB doesn't use **named** parameters (like the native SQL Server client does) - it uses **positional** parameters (so that's what I replaced your named parameter with just a `?`). Since there's only one parameter, this shouldn't be a problem here - but you need to properly define the `SQLCmd`'s parameter (and set its value)

Comment: Thanks very much! Been going through PowerPoints from my Computer Science teacher for the past 2 hours trying to get this to work just for that to be the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Connections and Commands can use unmanaged resources so, they need to have their `.Dipose` methods called to release these resources. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this and also `.Close` the connection. Your database objects must be local to the method where they are used for this to work.

**Always use Parameters** to avoid Sql injection.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim AreYouSureEdit = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If AreYouSureEdit = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
                SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand("DELETE From STAFF WHERE staffID = @currentStaffID", cn)
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@currentStaffID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(editStaffIDTxtBox.Text)
            cn.Open()
            SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MsgBox("Record Deleted.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End If
End Sub
```